# How to return Javascript from an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need one Action return a JavaScript fragment.

In MVC 5 we have:

```
return JavaScript("alert('hello')");
```

but in MVC 6 we don´t.

Is there a way to do this now ?

Comment: return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello world!');</script>");

Comment: @din Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Christos as you wish :-)

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved by returning **[ContentResult <sup>MSDN</sup>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult(v=vs.118).aspx)**

```
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello world!');</script>");
```

or other way would be making use of ajax

```
return json(new {message="hello"});  

 $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){alert(data.message)},    
    });
```

Comment: Can you please include an explanation with this as well. Code only answers are typically frowned upon because they lack reasoning. Perhaps include a link to MSDN or something that references Content?

Comment: The first option does not work with mvc 6. Nothing happens, at all.

Comment: Can you add more to your code rather than a simple return statment, client side, controller code. I would prefer second option though.

Comment: Actually I need to render a partial view and present it in a bootbox control.

Comment: where do I put the ajax code. I don't have a view. I just want to display alert.

Answer (score 6):

I think we can implment JavaScriptResult ourselves since it is not supported officially. It is easy:

```
public class JavaScriptResult : ContentResult
{
    public JavaScriptResult(string script)
    {
        this.Content = script;
        this.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    }
}
```

Comment: In your controller you must be add:

public class JavaScriptController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return new JavaScriptResult("var jjj=123;console.log(jjj);");
        }
    }

in html page you must be add:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript/Index">
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Currently ASP.NET MVC 6 doesn't support `JavaScriptResult` like in MVC 5. An interesting discussion for this can be found here (there's some solutions for your problem too): https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2953

Personally I think that sending JS code to the client is a bad thing (send the client the data that the JS needs and then perform the functions invocations there) but it seems that there's a valid situation for this (look at the last comment).

Comment: This will be a challenge for my actual project. But I will give a try.

Comment: Sending??? No! It should be used for sharing of dynamically create JS using site endpoint. For example for dynamically created constants.